# Redirect after logging in with $auth in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js

I'm having trouble redirecting my user when logging in with nuxt's default $auth configuration. Here's my problem:

- Whenever I log in using the laravel/jwt provider, it redirects to my website home.
- I have several points on the site where I need to open a modal with my login and I need to keep the user logged in on the same page he is on.
- But I already tried to follow the documentation using the fake redirect flag and still I couldn't.

Is there any way to log in, if he is not on a specific page, such as the login page, he just refreshes instead of redirecting to the / route?

My usage:

```
async login() {
      try {
        this.loading(true)
        await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelJWT', { data: this.form })
        if (!this.redirectHome) {
          this.$router.back()
          this.$emit('is-logged')
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.loginError = true
      } finally {
        this.loading(false)
      }
    },
```

Comment: You could `await` the `loginWith` method, make a conditional and redirect if needed IMO: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth#loginwithstrategyname-args

Comment: I tried this approach, but it redirects before entering the then of my promise

Comment: Can you share a [repro]? Also, prefer using the `async/await` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this.$auth.options.redirect = false` before `loginWith` it will disable redirect.
when the promise resolved then you can call other api to refresh data or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

My resolution:

```
async login() {
      await this.$auth
        .loginWith('laravelJWT', { data: this.form })
        .then(() => {
          this.loading(true)
          if (this.$route.name !== 'login') {
            this.$router.go(this.$router.currentRoute)
          }
          this.$emit('is-logged')
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.loginError = true
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.loading(false)
        })
    },
```

Comment: Try to not mix and match `async/await` and `.then()`. Nice to know that your solution works!